# Usage of care: can I say that "I care about how the news paper wrote about me"?

Tags: word-usage

Can I say that "I care about how the news paper wrote about me"

I am sure about the usage that I care about my family. 
It implies that I love my family, I am emotionally attached with them, and they are important to me.

However, can I say that " I care about the news paper wrote about me "?
I ask because I am not implying that I LOVE the news paper, but it is true that how they wrote about me is important to me, and I am emotionally attached to what it says. 
More precisely, I will be happy if it says something good about me, and vice versa.
PS: is EMOTIONALLY ATTACHED describes correctly the situation?

Comment: I wouldn't say: "I care about *HOW* the newspaper (one word) wrote about", it sounds a bit stilted, whereas the negative **"I don't care *what* the newspapers write about me"** sounds more natural. For the affirmative sense, I would say: "It matters (OR) I care what the newspapers say about me."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use care to indicate that you are worried or concerned about something, without an underlying meaning that you care for it.

[Dictionary.com definition:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/care)

> verb (used without object), cared, caring.
>
> 7. to be concerned or solicitous; have thought or regard.
> 8. to be concerned or have a special preference (usually used in negative constructions): I don't care if I do.
> 9. to make provision or look out (usually followed by for): Will you care for the children while I am away?
> 10. to have an inclination, liking, fondness, or affection (usually followed by for): Would you care for dessert? I don't care for him
>     very much.
>
> verb (used with object), cared, caring.
>
> 11. to feel concern about: He doesn't care what others say.
> 12. to wish; desire; like: Would you care to dance?